# Ajax upload POST data not inserting into database in Rails 3

Tags: ajax, file, ruby-on-rails-3, upload

I'm having a heck of a time grabbing a param from my POST array and inserting it into a MySQL database. The file is submitted to a RAILS 3 controller that should pull the filename and use it as a value in an SQL statement. This is my controller:

```
def upload
    @item= Item.new(params[:qqfile])
    Rails.logger.info("PARAMS: #{params.inspect}")
    # if params array contains :qqfile
    unless params[:qqfile].empty?
      # model should:
      # copy file to uploads directory
      render_success
      if @item.save

      else
        render :text => 'database did not save'
      end
      # redirect to render success action
    else
      render :text => '{success:false}'
    end
  end
```

The log shows that the query is running but with a NULL value:

```
Started POST "/item/upload?qqfile=1eCH6.jpg" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri Jan 07 09:16:0
9 -0700 2011
  Processing by ItemController#upload as HTML
  Parameters: {"qqfile"=>"1eCH6.jpg"}
PARAMS: {"qqfile"=>"1eCH6.jpg", "controller"=>"item", "action"=>"upload"}
Rendered text template (0.0ms)
  SQL (0.0ms)  INSERT INTO `items` (`name`, `qqfile`, `created_at`, `updated_at`
) VALUES (NULL, NULL, '2011-01-07 16:16:10', '2011-01-07 16:16:10')
Completed 200 OK in 359ms (Views: 16.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

The key is there in the array. I'm confused why the controller isn't using its value for the value in the SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) for file uploads. Handling uploads can be a pain, and paperclip makes it much easier.

Comment: In this case, it was an ajax upload that would take place before the actual form is submitted. Paperclip is GREAT when it comes to generic file uploads... but is not so great when you're doing ajax with a progress bar.